# How to get rid of ElementNotFound error in Capybara (JRuby)

Tags: jruby, capybara

I'm new to capybara and jruby. As one of my practice, i used way2sms site. After clicking Send SMS, the control was not able to find the element to enter the phone number.

```
require 'rubygems'
 require 'capybara'
 require 'capybara/dsl'
 require 'selenium-webdriver'
 include Capybara::DSL

  Capybara.run_server = false
  Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  visit "http://www.way2sms.com"
  page.find(:xpath, '/html/body/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a').click

    fill_in('username',:with=>"username")
    fill_in('password',:with=>"password")
    click_button('button')

    page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="quickclose1"]').click
    page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="quicksms"]').click

    page.fill_in('MobNo',:with=>"mobile number")
    page.fill_in('textArea',:with=>"Some message5")
    page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="Send"]').click
    click_button('Send SMS')
```

when i run this, it shows the following error,

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password
field with id, name, or label 'MobNo' found.
```

Anyone help me to clear this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information my guess is that one of these causes the field for mobile number to appear maybe through ajax?

```
 page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="quickclose1"]').click
 page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="quicksms"]').click
```

Do you run your scenario with @javascript? That would be what I would try first.
Since the default driver is rack_test and that can not handle any javascript. And to get capybara to use javascript driver which is selenium, by default, you need to tag your scenario in cucumber with @javascript. Or with :js => true if you're using RSpec. Read about it in the capybara readme [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master)

The root of the problem is that there is no input with id 'MobNo'. Are you sure that it is the correct id for the input field?
You can also see what the webpage looks like too cucumber/capybara by adding the step "Then show me the page" before the step that  fails.

Comment: Thank you for your effort... I'l figure it out. I'l try the scenario with Javascript, because the content is coming through Ajax only i think.